# EF Core entity not added to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

My entities are not added to a specific table.

While every other tables are working great, I have a specific one which is not and I can't find out why. In a same sequence, I have different add/update before a `SaveChangeAsync`, every query works fine except for one table where entities are not added.

I have checked the entity, its data is well filled.

After some investigations on why I had no data in this table, I used the immediate window to perform some tests, here is what I get for the sequence:

1. Count from table
2. Add an entity
3. Save `DBContext`
4. Count from table

**Count**

```
_DbContext.Attendees.Count()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (17ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [Attendees] AS [e]
Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Message","time":"2018-05-02T11:39:35.5327129Z","tags":{"ai.operation.parentId":"|d06def47-4faba4501b66147c.","ai.operation.id":"d06def47-4faba4501b66147c","ai.location.ip":"127.0.0.1","ai.operation.name":"POST Order/VerifyPayment [cartId]","ai.application.ver":"1.0.0.0","ai.internal.nodeName":"MyPC","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"MyPC","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"aspnet5c:2.1.1"},"data":{"baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{"ver":2,"message":"Executed DbCommand (17ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']\r\nSELECT COUNT(*)\r\nFROM [Attendees] AS [e]","severityLevel":"Information","properties":{"{OriginalFormat}":"Executed DbCommand ({elapsed}ms) [Parameters=[{parameters}], CommandType='{commandType}', CommandTimeout='{commandTimeout}']{newLine}{commandText}","elapsed":"17","commandTimeout":"30","commandText":"SELECT COUNT(*)\r\nFROM [Attendees] AS [e]","AspNetCoreEnv
ironment":"Development","commandType":"Text","DeveloperMode":"true","CategoryName":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command"}}}}
0
```

**Add entity**

```
_DbContext.Attendees.Add(attendees[0])
{Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalClrEntityEntry}
    Collections: {System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.INavigation, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.CollectionEntry>}
    Context: {Project.Data.DbContext}
    CurrentValues: {Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.CurrentPropertyValues}
    Entity (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry): {Project.Models.Attendee}
    Entity: {Project.Models.Attendee}
    InternalEntry: {Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalClrEntityEntry}
    IsKeySet: true
    Members: {System.Linq.Enumerable.Concat2Iterator<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.MemberEntry>}
    Metadata: {EntityType: Attendee}
    Navigations: {System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.INavigation, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.NavigationEntry>}
    OriginalValues: {Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.OriginalPropertyValues}
    Properties: {System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IProperty, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.PropertyEntry>}
    References: {System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.INavigation, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ReferenceEntry>}
    State: Added
```

**Save changes**

```
_DbContext.SaveChanges()
0
```

**Table Count**

```
_DbContext.Attendees.Count()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (19ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [Attendees] AS [e]
Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Message","time":"2018-05-02T11:40:05.8741131Z","tags":{"ai.operation.parentId":"|d06def47-4faba4501b66147c.","ai.operation.id":"d06def47-4faba4501b66147c","ai.location.ip":"127.0.0.1","ai.operation.name":"POST Order/VerifyPayment [cartId]","ai.application.ver":"1.0.0.0","ai.internal.nodeName":"MyPC","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"MyPC","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"aspnet5c:2.1.1"},"data":{"baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{"ver":2,"message":"Executed DbCommand (19ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']\r\nSELECT COUNT(*)\r\nFROM [Attendees] AS [e]","severityLevel":"Information","properties":{"{OriginalFormat}":"Executed DbCommand ({elapsed}ms) [Parameters=[{parameters}], CommandType='{commandType}', CommandTimeout='{commandTimeout}']{newLine}{commandText}","elapsed":"19","commandTimeout":"30","commandText":"SELECT COUNT(*)\r\nFROM [Attendees] AS [e]","AspNetCoreEnv
ironment":"Development","commandType":"Text","DeveloperMode":"true","CategoryName":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command"}}}}
0
```

As we can observe, the entity is attached successfully, but on save, nothing happens... What could cause this? It is declared as any other table. It has a Guid Id as key, which is set on code-side

**Additional information**

```
_DbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries<Attendee>().Count() => 1
```

and

```
_DbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries<Attendee>().ElementAt(0).Entity
```

gives an entity, with a set unique id and many other fields which have not much interest in this case.

After a `Save`, Entries.Count returns 0, but nothing has been added...

I have removed any foreign key in SQL that could interfere and any key besides primary key in the entity description.

`_DbContext.Attendees.FirstOrDefault()` runs the SQL statement, and returns null as expected as there is no entry in the DB.

If I do `_DbContext.Attendees.Add(new Attendee(){Id=Guid.NewId()})` it works... I will start from there...

Comment: Can you show the code where you add and save? The full controller or service I mean

Comment: Well, the return value of `SaveChanges` is how many operations it performed, which is obviously zero here. I really can't think of a reason it would not be saving unless there's a DB update exception or the entity already exists (in which case EF will merely attach, not add). In the latter case, if you're trying to do something like duplicate an entity, you need to make sure it's detached and then zero out/null the id, before you add it.

Comment: @Riscie it would be a bit complex to isolate that info :/

Comment: @ChrisPratt you may check the additional info I added

Answer (score 0):

Somehow it was breaking because there were `SELECT` statements (`ToListAsync` and `FirstOrDefaultAsync`) between `Add` and `UPDATE` calls. One of the `Add` statement got lost somewhere and I couldn't find why.

My solution has been to create a new `DbContext`, and keep on this `DbContext` only `SELECT` statements that were required to update some entities and move these `SELECT` as first statements.